# Using mail() causes 504 Gateway Time-out in Nginx

Tags: php, email, nginx, debian, sendmail

I just installed php, mysql, nginx, sendmail on debian 6.

Now the PHP pages work fine. But when I try to use a simple `mail()` test:

Example: `mail($to, $sub, $msg)`

it takes too long to finish (around 30+secs) then get I `504 Gateway Time-out` in my browser.

Funny thing is the email is actually sent.

BTW this is the error from the log:
`upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream`

Anybody knows what's causing this error?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I see your question is from '12 but answers are from '14. Just thought I'd ask - I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem in your sendmail. I recommend to install Postfix instead of sendmail and configure it in `php.ini`. Then check your `mail()` function.

Also you can try to use sendmail directly instead of using mail- function.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a problem with the ability for php to contact the mail server. Have you verified the following:

Iptables is off (or any other firewall for that matter)

Display the contents of the following:

Sendmail cfg

and the output of the following command

`netstat -punta` (not calling you a name here ;) )